# Transforming a column type range to Date in VBA (Match function)

Tags: excel, vba, match

I've been tried to find something to fix my problem two days ago but nothing works. My first question here and I am non-native english speaker, so I'm sorry for something bad in my text, but here we go:

I have a macro that create a new sheet and feed some data (in this new sheet) that came from home sheet that users will input data, besides some formulas that I create in VBA that will feed that new sheet too. Ok, so, after that, I have to use Offset + Match to create a variable (works fine in Excel) --I called **"ParcelaHoje"**-- that return a value based on a cell value right on the side. Them problem is that the two variables that I use in Match function is different. One of them is Date (**"MesAtual**") and the another is a Range, I think. I'm kind of confused with what type of variable will be a variable that contains dates in each cell. An array I suppose.
I've tried to use Application.Match instead of WorksheetFunction.Match, the return error is diferent, but still an error. That's not where the problem is, I think.
I've tried to declare a variable that contains that Range("B:B"), but not working too.

All the code below:

```
Sub criar_fluxo()

'ATIVAR ABA MACRO
Worksheets("MACRO").Activate

'DECLARA VARIAVEIS INPUTADAS PELO USUARIO
Dim MesAtual As Date
Dim MesFormalizacao As Date

ValorBruto = Range("E" & "2").Value
TaxaDeJuros = Range("D" & "2").Value
ValorParcela = Range("H" & "2").Value
NumeroDeParcelas = Range("F" & "2").Value
Carencia = Range("G" & "2").Value
MesFormalizacao = Range("J" & "2").Value
MesAtual = Range("I" & "2").Value
ParcelaInicial = Range("K" & "2").Value
ParcelaFinal = Range("L" & "2").Value

'ADD NOVA ABA
Sheets.Add
Range("A1", "H1").Interior.Color = vbBlue

'COLA VALORES DA ABA MACRO NA NOVA ABA
With ActiveSheet
Range("A1", "H1").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
Range("A1", "H1").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("A" & "1") = "N° PARCELA"
Range("B" & "1") = "MES PARCELA"
Range("C" & "1") = "JUROS"
Range("D" & "1") = "AMORTIZACAO"
Range("E" & "1") = "PARCELA ATUAL"
Range("F" & "1") = "SALDO DEVEDOR"
Range("G" & "1") = "VALOR PARCELA ADIANTADA"
Range("H" & "1") = "# MESES ADIANTADOS"
Range("F" & "2") = ValorBruto
SaldoDevedor = ValorBruto
Cells(2, 1) = 0
numRow = 3
Columns("A:H").AutoFit
'LOOP DA CARENCIA
    For numRow = 3 To numRow + Carencia - 2
    
        Juros = SaldoDevedor * TaxaDeJuros
        Range("C" & numRow) = Juros
        SaldoDevedor = SaldoDevedor + Juros
        Range("F" & numRow) = SaldoDevedor
        Range("A" & numRow) = 0
        Range("B" & numRow - 1) = MesFormalizacao
        MesFormalizacao = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(MesFormalizacao, 1)
        
    Next
        Range("B" & numRow - 1) = MesFormalizacao
        MesFormalizacao = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(MesFormalizacao, 1)
numRow = numRow
Amortizacao = 0
NumeroDaParcela = 1
'LOOP DAS PARCELAS REGULARES
    For numRow = numRow To numRow + NumeroDeParcelas - 1
    
        Juros = SaldoDevedor * TaxaDeJuros
        Range("C" & numRow) = Juros
        Range("E" & numRow) = ValorParcela
        Amortizacao = ValorParcela - Juros
        SaldoDevedor = SaldoDevedor - Amortizacao
        Range("D" & numRow) = Amortizacao
        Range("F" & numRow) = SaldoDevedor
        Range("A" & numRow) = NumeroDaParcela
        NumeroDaParcela = NumeroDaParcela + 1
        Range("B" & numRow) = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(MesFormalizacao, 0)
        MesFormalizacao = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(MesFormalizacao, 1)
    
    Next
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

FirstRow = Cells(2, 2).Row
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'ACHAR NUMERO DA PARCELA DE HOJE

ParcelaHoje = WorksheetFunction.Offset(Range("A1"), Application.Match(MesAtual, Range("B2:B" & LastRow), 0), 0)

'ParcelaAdiantada = ValorParcela / (1 + TaxaDeJuros) ^ 'DIFERENCA ENTRE ParcelaInicial e ParcelaHoje


End With


End Sub
```

The problem is in the line:
**ParcelaHoje = WorksheetFunction.Offset(Range("A1"), Application.Match(MesAtual, Range("B2:B" & LastRow), 0), 0)**
that return error *"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"*

I've tried to use that below, create a new variable type Variant with the range values:

```
Dim MonthRange As Range
Set MonthRange = Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Meses As Variant
Meses = MonthRange.Value
```

And then use that variable "**Meses"** instead of **"MonthRange"**, but it won't works anyway :(

I don't know what else to do, and it looks like that there is something very very simple and I can't see it.

Comment: When I use the MonthRange in Match formula, the error return is Type mismatch

Comment: There is no `Application.Offset`  You can use: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(Application.Match(MesAtual, Range("B2:B" & LastRow), 0)).Value`  But be aware that if the value is not found in the range it will error.  It would be better to ensure that the Match returns a value before trying to use it.

Comment: `Meses As Variant`  to `Dim Meses As Variant`

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're trying to do with code alone. Inserting an image will help us understand.

Comment: There is no `WorksheetFunction.Offset`, either (sorry, Scott). It's the *WorksheetFunction* object that doesn't support the *Offset* property.

Comment: At the end, I did what I wanted in a different way kkk. I create a For to see each cell of the range and if the cell contain the value that I want, take the value right of the side of it. It works very well. But until today I don't know how it will work with Offset + Match functions and this kind of killing me kkk